# Como adicionar métodos à uma classe nativa?

Tags: c#, .net, classes

Como adicionar funções em uma classe nativa do C#, no meu caso, tentei fazer em `System.Math` só como teste:

```
public class Math
{
    public static double test(double a)
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```

E chamá-lo assim:

```
Math.test(10);
```

Mas não obtive o resultado esperado. Como seria possível adicionar o método nesta classe?

Comment: Você chamou `Math.test(10)` simplesmente ? Colocou o resultado em uma variável ? Ou salvou em um arquivo de log ou exibiu no console/trace ?
O que você fez com o resultado ? Gerou algum erro do compilador ? Gerou alguma exceção em runtime ? Veja um exemplo que acabei de fazer baseado no seu: http://rextester.com/YZX58485
Tem 2 métodos, Dobro e Metade, como o nome já sugere, o Dobro multiplica o valor por 2 e o Metade divide por 2, funcionaram perfeitamente...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto não é possível hoje, e tem pouca vantagem fazer isto. Crie uma nova classe e boa.

```
public class MathExt {
    public static double test(double a) => a;
}

MathExt.test(10);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/StaticExtension.cs).

Está em estudos permitir *extension everything*, e aí poderá existir métodos de extensão estáticos, em tese poderia ser em classes estáticas.

Comment: Vou reforçar que não tem como estender uma classes estática, como quer saber a pergunta. A resposta aceita está estendendo a classe `Float32` e não `Math`, como está na pergunta. Eu fico com minha resposta, porque ela responde ao que foi perguntado. Se o desejo era perguntar outras coisa, deveria ter sido perguntado, por isso fechei a pergunta, a intenção era uma, mas o texto era outro.

Comment: Ok, percebi que sua resposta realmente era a mais correta e a que mais condizia com o que eu realmente queria, a marquei como correta, obrigado pela explicação da resposta do Rodolpho. Poderia agora tirar a marcação?

Comment: @Francisco não fechei porque você aceitou outra resposta. Eu preciso avaliar melhor porque ainda está confuso o que deseja de fato, o fechamento de não claro é porque não se sabe exatamente o que está sendo perguntado, e não qual a resposta aceita. Ficou uma coisa complicada porque tem respostas antagônicas bem votadas. Isso passa a mensagem errada, mostra que a pergunta deixou margem para interpretações equivocadas, ou seja, isso é a definição de não clara. Eu até achei que tinha entendido porque falava em `Math`. Eu acho que não deveria ter respondido e ter fechado antes de ter respostas.

Comment: "Ficou uma coisa complicada porque tem respostas antagônicas bem votadas." Isso não tem nada a ver, as pessoas podem ter votado só pelo fato da resposta ter sido bem elaborada e ter mostrado exemplos de utilização. A pergunta não tem erros, descreve exatamente qual meu problema, para não entende-la a pessoa tem que ser muito burra.

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que o que você esteja procurando chama-se **Extension Methods**.

Veja mais em : **[Métodos de extensão](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)** !

Utilizando este conceito, você pode criar extensões para todas as classes e estruturas, desde que as mesmas não sejam estáticas.

A classe Math é estática e não pode ser estendida:

[image: Erro no Visual Studio]

As demais respostas até parecem funcionar, mas na verdade você estaria acessando uma classe nova e não a existente :`System.Math`.

Veja a diferença abaixo:

[image: Classe Nova]

Lista de métodos da classe nova, em comparação com a lista de métodos da classe `System.Math` abaixo :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo um exemplo de como poderia ser uma extensão do double para você ter uma ideia:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double dez = 10;
        Console.WriteLine("Dobro(10) => {0}", dez.Dobro());
        Console.WriteLine("Metade(10) => {0}", dez.Metade());             
    }    
}

public static class DoubleEx
{
    public static double Dobro(this double a)
    {
        return a * 2;
    }

    public static double Metade(this double a)
    {
        return a / 2;
    }
}
```

Com a seguinte saída:
Dobro(10) => 20
Metade(10) => 5